# ReactJS how to display 5 page numbers at a time in pagination

Tags: arrays, reactjs

So I have this Pagination code,

```
class Pagination extends Component{

    render() {


        var { meta } = this.props.items2
        var numbers = !meta ? [] : Array.from({length: meta.pagination.total_pages },(v,k)=>k+1)
        console.log("data pagination", meta)
        return (
            <nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
              { !meta ? <span></span>
                : <ul className="pagination justify-content-center">
                            {meta.pagination.links.length === 0 ? <span></span> 
                                      : <li className="page-item">
                                          <button className="page-link" aria-label="Previous">
                                            <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
                                            <span className="sr-only">Previous</span>
                                          </button>
                                        </li>
                              }
                            {
                                numbers.map((item) => <li className={meta.pagination.current_page === item ? "page-item active" : "page-item"}><button className="page-link" onClick={() => this.props.pageNumber(item,"num")}>{item}</button></li>) 
                            }
                            {meta.pagination.links.length === 0 ? <span></span> 
                                      : <li className="page-item">
                                          <button className="page-link" aria-label="Next">
                                            <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
                                            <span className="sr-only">Next</span>
                                          </button>
                                        </li>
                            }
                    </ul>
              }
            </nav>
            )

    }
}
```

In which, it displays all the pages indicated in the api. 
It looks like this:
[image]

The next and previous buttons does not work yet. And all the pages are displayed. How can I make it that only 5 pages are displayed and when the nexy button is clicked then the next 5 pages will appear?

EDIT: as per @santosh answer, I am getting an error `Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.`

```
class Pagination extends Component{

    state = {
        startIndex : 0, 
        endIndex : 4
    }

  prevPage = () => {
        this.setState(prevState => ({
            startIndex : prevState.startIndex - 5,
            endIndex : prevState.endIndex - 5
        }));
    }

    nextPage = () => {
        this.setState(prevState => ({
            startIndex : prevState.startIndex + 5,
            endIndex : prevState.endIndex + 5
        }));
    }

    render() {
        var startIndex = this.state.startIndex
        var endIndex = this.state.endIndex
        var { meta } = this.props.items2
        var numbers = !meta ? [] : Array.from({length: meta.pagination.total_pages },(v,k)=>k+1)
        console.log("data pagination", meta)
        return (
            <nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
              { !meta ? <span></span>
                : <ul className="pagination justify-content-center">
                            {meta.pagination.links.length === 0 ? <span></span> 
                                      : <li className="page-item">
                                          <button className="page-link" onClick={
                                                        this.prevPage()
                                                    } aria-label="Previous">
                                            <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
                                            <span className="sr-only">Previous</span>
                                          </button>
                                        </li>

                              }
                            {numbers.slice(startIndex, endIndex).map(item => (
                                <li className={meta.pagination.current_page === item ? 'page-item active' : 'page-item'}>
                                <button className="page-link" onClick={() => this.props.pageNumber(item, 'num')}>
                                {item}
                                </button>
                                </li>
                                ))
                                    }
                            {meta.pagination.links.length === 0 ? <span></span> 
                                      : <li className="page-item">
                                          <button className="page-link" onClick={
                                                        this.nextPage()
                                                    } aria-label="Next">
                                            <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
                                            <span className="sr-only">Next</span>
                                          </button>
                                        </li>
                            }
                    </ul>
              }
            </nav>
            )

    }
}
```

this is the meta

[image]

I am accessing this pagination component from the index file. It's being called like this

```
<Pagination 
pageNumber={this.pageNumber}
items2={items2}/>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It can be done in below approach.

1) Define two state variable as below.

```
state = {..., startIndex : 0, endIndex : 4}
```

2) Then slice the **numbers** array with these two index.

```
{
    numbers.slice(startIndex, endIndex).map(item => (
        <li className={meta.pagination.current_page === item ? 'page-item active' : 'page-item'}>
            <button className="page-link" onClick={() => this.props.pageNumber(item, 'num')}>
                {item}
            </button>
        </li>
    ));
}
```

3) On click of next button, the state value should be updated using **setState**

**Prev click**

```
this.setState((prevstate)=>{
    startIndex : prevstate.startIndex - 5,
    endIndex : prevstate.endIndex - 5
})
```

**Next click**

```
this.setState((prevstate)=>{
    startIndex : prevstate.startIndex + 5,
    endIndex : prevstate.endIndex + 5
})
```

Additional condition to check the array limit can be added as per requirement.
Hope this help :)

Code has issue with binding that is onClick.

```
onClick={this.prevPage()}
onClick={this.nextPage()}
```

should be

```
onClick={this.prevPage}
onClick={this.nextPage}
```

Please find the working codepen : https://codepen.io/imsontosh/pen/zmdGdj?editors=0010

Comment: `Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.`

Comment: please provide more info such as this.props.meta, how are you rendering the component ?

Comment: This solution is Great!!

Comment: What if your number of pages is not a multiple of 5?